# Get all the times an items value comes up in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a data Frame with a list of teams and their goals. I have googled different ways to solve but I cant find a way that I want it done.

I have tried value_counts() And it seems to get all the Goals for each team I cant find a way to add them together.

```
HomeTeam      TeamsGoals
Liverpool          4
                   0
                   3
                   6
                   1
```

```
  matchdata.groupby("HomeTeam")["FullTimeHomeTeamsGoals"].value_counts()
```

I have tried many diffrent thing but I cant get the right output

My dataSet looks something like this:

```
HOME             AWAY               HOMEGOALS     AWAYGOALS
Liverpool       Man City               5             3
Man u           Man City               0             2
LiverPool       Man u                  6             2     
Man u           LiverPool              0             2    
Man City        Man U                  7             4
Man City        Liverpool              2             2
```

wanted output:

```
HOME           ToalScoreHome                       
Liverpool       11                            
Man City        9 
Man u           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use groupby and sum

```
matchdata.groupby('HOME')['HOMEGOALS'].sum()

HOME
LiverPool    6
Liverpool    5
Man City     9
Man u        0
Name: HOMEGOALS, dtype: int64
```

Or if `LiverPool` really has a differ case `Liverpool` then

```
matchdata.groupby(matchdata['HOME'].str.lower())['HOMEGOALS'].sum()

HOME
liverpool    11
man city      9
man u         0
Name: HOMEGOALS, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this does not work as you would expect is because `LiverPool != Liverpool`, so `groupby` won't do what you expect it to do, which makes sense why. Convert that, and try again:

```
df.replace({'LiverPool':'Liverpool'},inplace=True)
df.groupby('HOME',as_index=False)['HOMEGOALS'].sum()


        HOME  HOMEGOALS
0  Liverpool         11
1   Man City          9
2      Man u          0
```

Note you might need to do this for your other values if they are misspellings between them.